# Converting UTC time to timestamptz always adds the +01 offset in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, timezone, cast

In Postgres 9.5, I do the following to convert a `timestamptz` to the UTC timezone:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-02-20 15:15:54.000495+01' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

this outputs correctly `2016-02-20 14:15:54.000495` as `timestamp without timezone`.

I would like to store this value in a `timestamptz` column. However, when I do the following:

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2016-02-20 15:15:54.000495+01' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::timestamptz
```

I would expect to get `2016-02-20 14:15:54.000495` as `timestamptz`.

However, this query gives me `2016-02-20 14:15:54.000495+01` as `timestamptz`, which sadly doesn't even represent the original time.

Whats the reason of such behavior? How do I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple cast from `timestamp` to `timestamptz` assumes your current time zone. If you want the cast to assume UTC (or any other time zone) you have to use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct again:

```
SELECT (timestamptz '2016-02-20 15:15:54.000495+01' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

You may be missing that the [**`AT TIME ZONE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT) has two different use cases. It can transpose `timestamptz` to `timestamp` and vice versa.
Related answer with detailed explanation:

- [Confused about TIMESTAMPTZ internal conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35433929/939860)

Be aware that your statement does not make sense:

> I would expect to get `2016-02-20 14:15:54.000495` as `timestamptz`.

The text representation of `timestamptz` is always *displayed* as local time according to your current time zone setting, extended with an offset to UTC. The literal you display has no offset, so it is a `timestamp` literal, not `timestamptz`. Basics here:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tried copy-pasting your code, but I still got `2016-02-20 15:15:54.000495+01`

Comment: @NumberFour: That's how it's supposed to be - as opposed to "this query gives me `2016-02-20 14:15:54.000495+01`" in your question. This might help to understand: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860